# Double every time brings different values

Tags: c#, algorithm, double, rounding

It's my generating algorithm it's generating random double elements for the array which sum must be 1

```
    public static double [] GenerateWithSumOfElementsIsOne(int elements)
    {
        double sum = 1;
        double [] arr = new double [elements];

        for (int i = 0; i < elements - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = RandomHelper.GetRandomNumber(0, sum);
            sum -= arr[i];
        }

        arr[elements - 1] = sum;

        return arr;
    }
```

And the method helper

```
    public static double GetRandomNumber(double minimum, double maximum)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
    }
```

My test cases are:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase(7)]
    [TestCase(5)]
    [TestCase(4)]
    [TestCase(8)]
    [TestCase(10)]
    [TestCase(50)]
    public void GenerateWithSumOfElementsIsOne(int num)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, RandomArray.GenerateWithSumOfElementsIsOne(num).Sum());   
    }
```

And the thing is - when I'm testing it returns every time different value like this cases :
`Expected: 1
But was:  0.99999999999999967d

Expected: 1
But was:  0.99999999999999989d`

But in the next test, it passes sometimes all of them, sometimes not.

I know that troubles with rounding and ask for some help, dear experts :)

Comment: Round up errors are usual for `float` and `double`; just add *tolerance* into the tests: `Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(RandomArray.GenerateWithSumOfElementsIsOne(num).Sum() - 1.0) < 1e-8);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

> In computing, floating-point arithmetic is arithmetic using formulaic
>   representation of real numbers as an approximation so as to support a
>   trade-off between range and precision. For this reason, floating-point
>   computation is often found in systems which include very small and
>   very large real numbers, which require fast processing times. A number
>   is, in general, represented approximately to a fixed number of
>   significant digits (the significand) and scaled using an exponent in
>   some fixed base; the base for the scaling is normally two, ten, or
>   sixteen.

In short, this is what floats do, they dont hold every single value and do approximate. If you would like more precision try using a `Decimal` instead, or adding tolerance by an epsilon (an upper bound on the relative error due to rounding in floating point arithmetic)

```
var ratio = a / b;
var diff = Math.Abs(ratio - 1);
return diff <= epsilon;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Round up errors* are frequent in case of floating point types (like `Single` and `Double`), e.g. let's compute an *easy sum*:

```
  // 0.1 + 0.1 + ... + 0.1 = ? (100 times). Is it 0.1 * 100 == 10? No!
  Console.WriteLine((Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Sum(i => 0.1)).ToString("R"));
```

Outcome:

```
  9.99999999999998
```

That's why when comparing *floatinfg point* values with `==` or `!=` add *tolerance*:

```
// We have at least 8 correct digits
// i.e. the asbolute value of the (round up) error is less than tolerance
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(RandomArray.GenerateWithSumOfElementsIsOne(num).Sum() - 1.0) < 1e-8);
```